# drupal access denied after dns change

Tags: drupal, dns

I just did a dns change on a site and now can't log in. It was being developed under a temporary url and now it's ready to go live. All of the pages/images/content are there. I just can't log in. I tried export/import as mentioned here: http://drupal.org/node/1042784, but the import won't go. Do I have to drop or empty all of the tables before import? Is this even a good/correct way to fix the issue?

I've searched google, drupal and this site.  I've asked this question on the drupal forum and at my hosting company.  No answers yet.  I desperately need to log in to this site.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Does the cookie domain in settings.php match the new DNS entry? If not try changing cookie_domain to the the new domain name.

To start with just dump the database and restore it to a database with another name to see if makes any difference. Assuming you use MySQL, to dump and restore the database from the console run something like this:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p drupaldb > drupaldb.dump
```

Then login in to mysql and drop and create database with a new name (don't forget collate and character set if you need that):

```
mysql> show create database drupaldb;
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database  | Create Database                                                   |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| drupaldb  | CREATE DATABASE `drupaldb` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE `drupaldb_new` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
```

Don't forget to grant privileges for a user to access the new database.

To restore:

```
mysql -uroot -p drupaldb_new < drupaldb.dump
```

Now you should have a new database. Change settings.php with the new database name and database user.

Comment: Yes, I did try that as well as base_url. It did not help.

Comment: If you comment out the cookie_domain variable, does it make any difference?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  Does it matter if I use phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes, you can use phpMyAdmin for the dump and restore process.

Comment: I know this is REALLY stupid to ask, but I want to make sure. Is dump and export the same thing?  I did an export earlier today.

Comment: That is relevant question - I don't use the tool MySelf but according to this description http://drupal.org/node/81993 it is indeed a dump. But be sure to restore it to a database with a new name so that the original database is intact.

Comment: Ok, I created a new database with the same name but a 2 added on the end, added a user and password with all rights. Imported my "dump" successfully.  Changed the settings.php, but I'm still getting access denied when I try to log in.  I'm loggin in with the existing drupal id's, not the database user I just created.  Is that right?

Comment: oops, I didn't drop the original database.  Would that matter?

Comment: I dropped the original database and when I went to the site, got a bunch of mysql errors.  So I imported the data back to the original site and can access the pages, but still access denied when I try to log in.  So it seems the original is connected somewhere other than settings.php??

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure what has happened now, but it's fixed. I have been working on this all day with my hosting company as well. Did multiple database drops, creates, settings.php changes. They said in the end it was the cookie_domain that they commented out. That was the first thing I tried. So something got tweaked along the way and it's working with the original database. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Commenting out (or changing the value of) $cookie_domain in sites/default/settings.php solved the problem for me.